# How would you send a notification to an iPhone lock screen?

Tags: ios, notifications, lockscreen

How would you send a notification to the lock screen of an iPhone from an app when something occurs?

Comment: I have done my best to answer below. In future questions, please take the time to include as much specificity as possible and be certain that you have done your due diligence in researching the issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

That kind of notification is known as a push notification (different from NSNotification). [Here's](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12) a tutorial on how to get up and running with Apple Push Notifications (APNs). There are also tools out there to streamline the process, such as Parse.com and Push.io, though I cannot speak to the quality of either of those products.

Comment: ive seen that but i'd like to know how to get them onto the lockscreen and drop down

Comment: If I understand you correctly APNs have that behavior by default (depending on user preferences).